# What is a "Slovenian Cadence"?

Tags: theory, terminology, cadence

I recently acquired a large collection of music theory review materials. In it, I came across the term "Slovenian cadence." Does anyone know what this might be?

Unfortunately, the review materials came from an untold number of sources acquired over several years (if not decades), and there's no way of identifying who it was that actually used this term.

Online searches for "slovenian cadence" only seem to provide results for Melania Trump's speech patterns (!).

Does anyone know what this might be? I have *never* come across this term anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't offer personal knowledge, but [this link](https://quizlet.com/362889948/comps-flash-cards/) at quizlet states that it's iii6 to I, in a couple of variations:

> **Perfect Slovenian cadence** - iii6 to I (tonic in both soprano and bass of I)
>
> **Imperfect Slovenian cadence** - iii6 to I (tonic not in both soprano and bass of I)

Comment: I'll note that iii6 is this close to being V13 (except no 7th).

Comment: It seems to me that this iii6 is really just a V chord with a non-chord tone (likely an escape tone).