# What is the difference between a cadential V6-5 and iii6?

Tags: satb

Please have a look at my harmonization. I am having difficulty labelling the V chords in this harmonization. I have labelled them as V chords with a 6-5 suspension. Would this labelling be correct since they resolve to I chords? When would these V chords be seen as something else? like maybe iii6 chords?

[image]

Comment: Well, technically a suspension must be “suspended” from a previous chord, so it can’t start a piece. Not saying it ain’t a V, just that it would be an upper neighbor tone.

Comment: Is this in the middle of the piece?

Comment: As I look more, I realize the second (cadential) chord can't be called a suspension either; its F# isn't coming from an F# in the previous chord. I *would* with total confidence analyze it as a V, though, because, well, cadence! (Also, to call it a iii, you'd have to explain the big ol' E in the tenor.)

Comment: Dekka the note before the F# is a D in the previous bar so you are right it is not a suspension because a suspension needs to be held from the previous bar as a common tone or be introduced by step right?

Comment: Andy then the E in the second one does mean it cant be a iii6 but what about the 1st one? Arent these just cadential 64 chords? I know the 4th isnt there but still.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post the preceding context as well. I was shying away from saying definitively that the first one was *not* a iii because it might make sense at the start of a phrase. If it's in fact another cadence, then all the more reason to call it a V as well. (But is it? How many phrases, and how many cadences, are we dealing with here?)

Comment: It sounds like a cadential V64 to me.... anyone please tell me why they think I am wrong :)

Comment: @armani - If it were a cadential V6/4, then it either has scale degree 2 on the bottom (a more naive reading) or it's what quite a lot of places would label a I6/4 chord and would therefore have scale degrees 1 and 3 in it. Your claimed V6 in your claimed V6-5 has only scale degrees 5, 7, 3 and sometimes 2 in it, and it always has scale degree 5 on the bottom. I can't call that a V6/4 chord, ever.

Comment: Ok so then what?

Comment: Related: [What is a "Slovenian Cadence?"](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/80362/21766) Like Athanasius, I *strongly* recommend *not* calling these iii6 chords.

Answer (score 3):

Some people would label these as (incomplete) V<sup>13</sup> chords.  Others would label them with a symbol like V<sup>sub6</sup>, indicating that a sixth above the bass is substituted for the 5th above the bass.  (However, in your second example, you actually have both, so maybe V<sup>add6</sup>?)

It's clearly a dominant function chord, and they are quite common, even without the 6-5 resolution.  That is, lots of cadences will go directly from a V<sup>sub6</sup> to I.

One thing you should *not* label these is iii<sup>6</sup>.  That's not their function.  They're just one variety of altered dominant chord, which are less commonly seen in Roman numeral analyses (even though they exist in a lot of classical harmony, especially in romantic period music).

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the root. `V` has root `A` and `iii` has root `F♯`. I know what is obvious, but then put it in context with moving to a `I` chord. The bass is playing the dominant and then the next is a `I`. That sets up a choice of either a *strong* progression of `V` to `I` or a *weak* progression of `iii` to `I`. The simple things is to call it `V` to `I` and whatever happens with `F♯` and `E` above is decorative.

If the next chord was some other modal region chord, like `vi`, the label `iii` might make sense as a passage in the modal region. But that doesn't happen here.

The name of the melodic, non-chord tone device will depend on the exact line, but there is a name for most everything. Your bar 2 to 3 occurrence can be called an appoggiatura. If you get all picky about NCT definitions, the first bar is tricky, because there is no *approach*, but I think appoggiatura would be an OK label. If you swapped the melodic order to `E F♯ D` you could call it an *escape tone* pattern.

> It sounds like a cadential V64 to me.... anyone please tell me why they think I am wrong :)

Well, it's wrong, because there isn't a fourth above the bass.

But, I think your comment helps make the point about the chord being a dominant and not a mediant. If you omit the `C♯` so that it were just bass `A` and `F♯` above you would essentially have melodic descent `MI RE DO` above a bass `A` to `D` (the first iteration the bass moves to `F♯` for an imperfect cadence to `I6`) and that melodic descent over that `SOL` to `DO` bass *is* the essential framework of a cadential 6/4.

Hearing that in the *outer* voices sort of confirms this is dominant to tonic harmony.

In notation I think of it like this: from  the outer voice skeleton of...

[image]

...common practice conventions would lead you to hear...

[image]

...therefore if you fill in the harmony this way...

[image]

...you would say the basic harmonic framework is still `V I` and the `F#` is an appoggiatura - or some other NCT - resolving down to the chord tone `E`.

Comment: @armani, I added some notation examples. Sometimes it's easier to say with music notation than words.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am still hearing a cadential V64 effect... cant help it :)  Although I hear what you mean about the 4th